# HTT, 4.2.4.3, Diagonal embedding.

Tags: simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

This is [Lem. 4.2.4.3](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/HTT.pdf) of HTT.

> $K$ is a simplicial set. $C$ an $\infty$-category. There is a diagonal embedding $\delta:C \rightarrow Fun(K, C)$

What is this map and how does it exist? Here Fun(-,-) is the internal hom in $Set_\Delta$, category of simplicial sets.

---

The only possible map I can think of is the adjunct map induced by projection 
$$C \times K \rightarrow C $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the map that takes $c$ to the constant functor whose value is $c$. As you guessed, this map is the adjunct to the projection $C \times K \to C$.